# How can I echo the result of function with a range?

Tags: vimscript, functions, range, echo

If I have a function that takes a range, how can I echo the return value of the function?

For example, the following does not work:

```
:echo 2,8call MyFunction()
```

Answer (score 4):

I looked into this, and I could not find a direct way of doing it. However, one possibility is to create an auxiliary function, that is:

```
function! Range() range abort
  return RangeAux(a:firstline, a:lastline)
endfunction

function! RangeAux(lnum1, lnum2) abort
  echo a:lnum1
  echo a:lnum2
endfunction

1,3call Range()
call RangeAux(1,3)
```

Answer (score 3):

@Karl's answer is pretty good but you can also use `execute()`:

```
echo execute("1,2call Range()")
```

You can even use variables for the range:

```
let l1=1
let l2=2
echo execute(l1 . "," . l2 . "call Range()")
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is closer to answering the original question. Very neat!

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I don't know which answer is closer to the original question: mine is shorter to write but I find yours more pleasant to read :)

Comment: I could not get this to work. It just echoes a blank line. The return value is not echoed. Did you test this with a trivial function?

Comment: This should not work since the return value of `execute(command)` is what is to be echoed by the `command`. Here the command `1,2call Range()` does not echo anything so `execute()` return `''`.  Basically, using `call` you are not be able to get the return value, unless you set a global variable instead of using `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `call` you are not able to get the return value of the function, regardless whether `range` is used or not.

Aside from @Karl's answer, you can set some variable instead of using `return`. Such as

```
function! Range() range abort
  let toreturn = 'my value'
  let s:retval = toreturn
endfunction
```

Comment: Yes, you can get the return value from the function using `call()`. From `:h call()`: `Returns the return value of the called function. {dict} is for functions with the "dict" attribute.  It will be used to set the local variable "self". |Dictionary-function|`